# IIS Queuing Requests?

Tags: c#, iis, async-await, windows-10

I’ve created a Windows 10 Universal App using MvvmCross and Stephen Cleary’s excellent AsyncEx library.

**Update 27/10/2015 15:43 - Stephen has answered the question. Tested and proven correct.**

In a view, I bind a ListView to a property in the ViewModel that asynchronously loads a collection of place holder view models called AssignableTaskPlaceholderViewModel (using AsyncEx functionality).

The data comes from a Web API service which I’ve also created.
For my test harness, the collection is loaded with 12  AssignableTaskPlaceholderViewModel with each simply holding an ID value.

The DataTemplate for the ListView items then binds elements to a property on the AssignableTaskPlaceholderViewModel called AssignableTaskViewModel. This asynchronously calls another Web API method to return detailed data (again using AsyncEx functionality). This method is currently returning mock data.

When I run the App, I would expect to see:

1)  The initial loading of the placeholder collection taking a small amount of time, then

2)  The detailed data for each item in the list loaded **concurrently**, taking roughly the same amount of time for the data to load.

What I actually see is the detailed data being loaded **sequentially** i.e. it looks like IIS is queuing the requests, processing them one at a time.

Shown below is some debug data, which shows that the initial requests processed within a second, with the responses taking between 0 and 4 seconds to complete, even though each method call is doing the same thing.

**My question is: why is this occurring?**

Start for Task ID 1050100111000000000034373 at 20/10/2015 15:09:52

Start for Task ID 1050100111000000000034398 at 20/10/2015 15:09:52

Start for Task ID 1050100111000000000034402 at 20/10/2015 15:09:52

Start for Task ID 1050100111000000000034407 at 20/10/2015 15:09:52

**Start for Task ID 1050100111000000000034431 at 20/10/2015 15:09:53**

Start for Task ID 1050100111000000000034433 at 20/10/2015 15:09:53

Start for Task ID 1050100111000000000034454 at 20/10/2015 15:09:53

Start for Task ID 1050100111000000000034479 at 20/10/2015 15:09:53

Start for Task ID 1050100111000000000034483 at 20/10/2015 15:09:53

Start for Task ID 1050100111000000000034488 at 20/10/2015 15:09:53

Start for Task ID 1050100111000000000034512 at 20/10/2015 15:09:53

End for Task ID 1050100111000000000034373 at 20/10/2015 15:09:53

Start for Task ID 1050100111000000000034514 at 20/10/2015 15:09:53

End for Task ID 1050100111000000000034512 at 20/10/2015 15:09:53

End for Task ID 1050100111000000000034514 at 20/10/2015 15:09:53

End for Task ID 1050100111000000000034402 at 20/10/2015 15:09:53

End for Task ID 1050100111000000000034407 at 20/10/2015 15:09:54

End for Task ID 1050100111000000000034398 at 20/10/2015 15:09:54

End for Task ID 1050100111000000000034483 at 20/10/2015 15:09:55

End for Task ID 1050100111000000000034479 at 20/10/2015 15:09:55

End for Task ID 1050100111000000000034488 at 20/10/2015 15:09:56

End for Task ID 1050100111000000000034454 at 20/10/2015 15:09:56

End for Task ID 1050100111000000000034433 at 20/10/2015 15:09:57

**End for Task ID 1050100111000000000034431 at 20/10/2015 15:09:57**

If I use fake data (rather than calling the Web API methods at all), with a deliberately added delay I can see that the View/ViewModel/AsyncEx plumbing is working fine.

**More details:**

1)  I’m calling the Web API using **Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient**. I use a single instance of HttpClient for all Web API method calls (which I believe is best practice).

2)  The Web API method calls do not require authentication or an HTTPS connection.

3)  For the HttpBaseProtocolFilter (used for the HTTPClient) I’ve set MaxConnectionsPerServer to 100.

4)  The Web API project targets .Net 4.6 (targetFramework="4.6"). I believe this version of .Net doesn’t limit the number of connections to the server i.e. **no need to add this to web.config**:      .

5)  I’ve used Async/Await “all the way”, in both the client App and the Web API methods.

6)  Session is enabled in the Web API project.

7) I'm running IIS 10 on my Win 10 development PC.

Comment: It would be better to share a piece of repro code, especially here since it involves client and server. IIS doesn't queue requests in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If read/write session mode is enabled, then ASP.NET will serialize the requests. ASP.NET does this regardless of whether they're synchronous or asynchronous.

Comment: Thanks ever so much; removing the session handling fixed the issue. Now working as I had expected.

Comment: @SergRogovtsev: See [the official docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx), particularly the section "Concurrent Requests and Session State".

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is the serialization done at the level of entire HTTP request, or at the moment of `Session` access?